# st_rasterize (template smaller than sf object)

Tags: raster, sf, rasterization, st

I need to rasterize an sf object that at the end must have the same cell size and be on the same grid of a defined raster object "template", because, eventually, I want to merge them.
The template is smaller than the sf object.

If using:
`x <-  st_rasterize(sf[, "field"], template)`

all works except that x is created only for the extent of the template. I want it to be of the same extent of sf (with pixel size of template and on its same grid)

Comment: Have you looked at the fasterize package? Very efficient and easy to implement. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fasterize/vignettes/using-fasterize.html

Answer (score 0):

The key to your goal is to extend the template raster with function `extend`, and then perform the rasterize function:

```
library(raster)
library(sf)

#build a first raster and populate it with random values
r <- raster(xmn = -150, xmx =- 120, ymx = 60, ymn = 30, ncol = 36, nrow = 18)
values(r) <- runif(1:ncell(r))

# build a triangle polygon from the raster extent and grow it larger than the raster with
# st_buffer
mp = matrix(c(-150,30,-120,30,-150,60,-150,30), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
pol = st_polygon(list(mp))
pol_buff = st_buffer(pol,10)

# apparently rasterize only uses spatial* objects
pol_sp = as(pol_buff, "Spatial")

# now we perform the extension
r_x = extend(r, pol_sp)
pol_r = rasterize(pol_sp, r) # not extended, for comparison
pol_r_ex = rasterize(pol_sp, r_x) # extended to  buffered polygon
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
image(pol_r, main = "rasterized with normal raster", xlim = c(-160,-110), ylim = c(20,70))
grid(col = "black")
image(pol_r_ex, main = "rasterized with extended raster",  xlim = c(-160,-110), ylim = c(20,70))
grid(col = "black")
```

[image]